# Combining State and List Monads

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad, non-deterministic

Consider the following Haskell code:

```
import Control.Monad.State

test :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
test = runStateT $ do
    a <- lift [1..10]
    modify (+a)
    return a

main = print . test $ 10
```

This produces the following output:

```
[(1,11),(2,12),(3,13),(4,14),(5,15),(6,16),(7,17),(8,18),(9,19),(10,20)]
```

However I would like to produce the following output instead:

```
[(1,11),(2,13),(3,16),(4,20),(5,25),(6,31),(7,38),(8,46),(9,55),(10,65)]
```

This is easy to do in an impure language like JavaScript:

```js
function test(state) {
    var result = [];

    for (var a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
        result.push([a, state += a]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

How do you do the same thing in Haskell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Haskell types and the logic of your JavaScript code doesn't match: the JS code has two values in the state (the Int, and the returned list). In contrast, `StateT Int [] a` doesn't really have a list in the state; rather, it runs stateful actions multiple times (with the initial state unchanged for each run) and collects all the results in a list.

In other words, the JS code has type `State (Int, [(Int, Int)]) [(Int, Int)]`. But this is too literal a translation and we can write more elegant Haskell code.

Sticking to the `State` monad, we can return a list with `mapM` or `forM`:

```
test2 :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
test2 = evalState $ 
    forM [1..10] $ \a -> do
        s <- get <* modify (+a)
        return (a, s)
```

Some `lens` magic can make it more similar to the JS code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

import Control.Lens

test3 :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
test3 = evalState $ 
    forM [1..10] $ \a -> (a,) <$> (id <+= a)
```

However, we can do away with `State` altogether, and it's the best approach here, I think:

```
import Control.Monad (ap)

test4 :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
test4 n = ap zip (tail . scanl (+) n) [1..10]
-- or without ap : zip [1..10] (drop 1 $ scanl (+) n [1..10])
```

Comment: The function `forM` is exactly what I needed to sequence my `State` actions. Thank you.

Comment: You can avoid the TupleSections and the lambda : `\a -> (a,)` is exactly `(,)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your series is quadratic and can be generated more simply:

```
series = fmap (\x -> (x, quot (x*x + x) 2 + 10)) [1..]
```

If you want a recurrence relation you might write it as this:

```
series :: [(Int,Int)]
series = let
  series' x y = (x, x + y) : series' (x + 1) (x + y)
  in series' 1 10
```

There is no compelling reason that I see to use monads.